# Straightforward migration AngularJS Promises from Success/Error to Then

Tags: angular-promise

I just had a (quite stupid on my behalf) problem on how to migrate from Angular 1.3 promises to Angular 1.5 promises, not code-wise but the way I was using them. Yet I might not be the most stupid person of the planet, so I am referring to you, Joy, my only inferior :-p

I was using promises as the result of a method (e.g. a service method), so the resolver would know what happened. E.g.

```
function myLogin(user,pass) {
    return $http({url:'/auth/login', data:{user:user,pass:pass}).
           success(function (r) { loggedin = true; }).
           error(function (r) { loggedin = false; });
}
```

and afterwards I could also write:

```
myLogin("Joe","12345").success(function (r) { console.log("WOW!"); }).
                      .error(function (r) { console.error(":-("); });
```

Now, after replacing the success/error with then, **this is no longer possible** if you keep this code form.
*This is due to the face that `then` is not returning the original promise, but the result of the function that executed.*

So if I write:

```
function myLogin(user,pass) {
    return $http({url:'/auth/login', data:{user:user,pass:pass}).
           then(function (r) { loggedin = true; } ,
                function (r) { loggedin = false; });
}

myLogin("Joe","12345").then(function (r) { console.log("WOW!"); },
                            function (r) { console.error(":-("); });
```

the `then` below is getting what the first pair of functions (whichever was executed) returned!

What should I do?

**TIP** : I've read there is an option to re-enable the success/error via the $http provider, but that wont last for long...

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer is so simple that, since I didn't realized it at first, I've spent a good hour searching with no results. All those that hadn't even asked were right!

All you have to do (dear Joy) is to modify the `myLogin` function and keep the original promise. Apply then on it, and also return that **original** promise from the function. I.e.

```
function myLogin(user,pass) {
    var promise = $http({url:'/auth/login', data:{user:user,pass:pass});
    promise.then(function (r) { loggedin = true; } ,
                 function (r) { loggedin = false; });
    return promise;
}

myLogin("Joe","12345").then(function (r) { console.log("WOW!"); },
                            function (r) { console.error(":-("); });
```

This way, making this minimal adaptation, you can migrate your with minimal effort.
Of course the new `then` idea that allows you to select what to return is a lot more powerful and probably if you have the time to redesign your code, will be a lot better in many aspects.